# fill foreign key from primary key using asp and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am writing a course and package form in asp.net using c# as I am new I am facing problem when executing my task is to insert the foreign key of that selected item in database so I make three tables `courses` which contains `Id` (pk) and `Course-name`, `Pkg-code` contain `Id` (pk), `Pkg-name` and last table is `Pkg` which contains `Pkg-id` (fk) referencing the `Pkg-Code(Id)` and `Course-Id` (fk) referencing `Courses(Id)`.

Now what I have to do is when I select the package from drop down and course from check box in web app the Id's of that selected item will insert in the third table `Pkg` via foreign key now the problem I am facing is when I execute it error is generating cannot insert NULL values in `Course-Id`, my stored procedure is working fine when executing it the values inserted in the third table pkg and I want to make one to many relation in database, I have searched lot but cannot find required answer please help

```
<div>
  Select Pkg:  <asp:DropDownList ID ="drop1" runat="server">
               </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID ="check1" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from PKgCode ", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet da = new DataSet();

    data.Fill(da);

    drop1.DataSource = da;

    //drop1.DataValueField = "PkgName";
    drop1.DataTextField = "PkgName";
    drop1.DataValueField="Id";

    drop1.DataBind();

    conn.Close();

    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Courses ", conn);

    SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd);

    DataSet ss = new DataSet();

    daa.Fill(ss);

    check1.DataSource = ss;
    check1.DataTextField = "CourseName";
    check1.DataValueField = "Id";
    check1.DataBind();

    conn.Close();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db"].ConnectionString;
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);

     SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand("Pkc", con);
     //SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("PkI", con);
     cmm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     //  cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmm.Parameters.Add("@pname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = drop1.SelectedValue;
     cmm.Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = check1.SelectedValue;

     con.Open();
     cmm.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the code in your stored procedure as it is not listed?

From looking at the Button1_Click code though, I am surprised that you are passing the parameter values to the stored procedures as NVarChar. Usualy the primarry key and foreign keys for a table would be an integer or in some cases a GIUD.

The first thing you nead to do is validate what you are getting back from drop1 and check11 controls. You should put a break point on the code line assigning the values to the parameters. When execution breaks, examine the value each control is returning. If they are not returning a valid value, then check the data being bound to the drop down control in the code in the page_load event.

If the values being returned are valid, then the error is in your stored procedure or the table that you are storing the data in. Are the foreign key values in the table of the same data type as the primary key values in the other two tables? Is there a coding error in your stored procedure?

Hope this helps.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pkc]
 @course nvarchar(50),
 @pname nvarchar(50)
AS
begin
 
  declare @courceID int
  declare @pkgID int
  select @courceID = Id from Courses where CourseName=@course
  select @pkgID = Id from PKgCode where PkgName=@pname
  insert into Pkg(CourseId,PkgId) values(@courceID, @pkgID) 
end`

Comment: i am passing the values of drop down and check box to stored procedure and it decides which id to be insert in database .

Comment: when i execute my procedure i works fine but when i execute my web app it generates an error that courses id cannot be null

Comment: I think that drop1.SelectedValue will be returning the Id of the selection and not the text. If this is the case, the stored procedure should be accpeting the primary keys and then not having to look them up. Otherwise, change the code to use check1.SelectedItem.Text to pass the actaul text to the stored procedure.

Comment: `SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand("stored", con);
     //SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("PkI", con);
     cmm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     //  cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmm.Parameters.Add("@pname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = drop1.SelectedItem.Text;
     cmm.Parameters.Add("@course", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = check1.SelectedItem.Text;`

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object and i have a error when i set check1.selecteditem.Text now what should i do in this case